# ruby on rails trouble sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

First up: This is my first question ever so please let me know how I can better ask questions in the future if I'm not doing it right here. I'm also relatively new to ROR!

Issue:

I'm trying to get my web app to send email in my development environment. It's not working. I'm not entirely sure why. Versions: Rails 4, Ruby 2.

current Browser issue:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ProfilesController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: profile

Extracted source (around line #83):81 82 83 84 85

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :email, :mobile, :address, :suburb, :postcode, :city, :state, :country)
end

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:83:in `profile_params'
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:45:in `block in update'
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:44:in `update'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Px14k13lkQa6d8V61K6dvwLN5xhqjieE8Yk5LjiW1z8=",
 "destination"=>"test@gmail.com",
 "commit"=>"Send Email",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Routes:

```
resources :profiles do
    put :email
end
```

profiles Controller:

```
def email
    destination = params[:to]
    share = Share.profile(@profile, destination)
    if destination =~ /@/ && share.deliver
        redirect_to @profile, notice: 'email sent :)'
    else 
        redirect_to @profile, notice: 'email failed :('
    end
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :email, :mobile, :address, :suburb, :postcode, :city, :state, :country)
end
```

Share Mailer:

```
class Share < ActionMailer::Base
    default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
    default from: "from@example.com"

    def profile(profile, destination)
        @user = profile.user
        @profile = profile
        mail to: destination, 
             subject: "#{@user.email} sent you stuff")
    end
end
```

view/profiles/show:

```
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Email
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Share my Info with someone</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_tag profile_path(@profile), method: :put do %>
          <%= label_tag :destination, "What email address would you like to send this to?" %>
          <%= text_field_tag :destination %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <%= submit_tag "Send Email", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Greatly appreciate any help! I'm not sure where I've gone wrong! Cheers

Comment: your code is calling the update action, not your email action. Change your form to submit to the email action.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling update action on submitting the form. Try to Change this line and try again:

```
        <%= form_tag profile_path(@profile), method: :put do %>
to
        <%= form_tag email_path(@profile), method: :put do %>
```

**Update:**

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag email_profile_path(profile: @profile), method: :put do %>
```

**Routes.rb:**

```
get 'email_profile' => 'profiles#email_profile'
```

**Controller:**

```
def email_profile
    @profile = params[:profile]
    destination = params[:to]
    share = Share.profile(@profile, destination)
    if destination =~ /@/ && share.deliver
        redirect_to @profile, notice: 'email sent :)'
    else 
        redirect_to @profile, notice: 'email failed :('
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for replying @sevenseacat and @anusha!

I changed the line to email_path but now I get:

NoMethodError in Profiles#show 
undefined method `email_path'

I'm not sure why it's undefined as it has been defined in the controller? I also tried 'email_profile_path(@profile) but had the same problem

Comment: also I'm using devise. I'm not sure if that's interfering at all?

Comment: @sss333 Have you included root for it in your routes.rb something like: `match '/email' => 'profile#email'`

Comment: ..still returns an error: 
    match '/email' => 'profile#email'

returns:

RuntimeError
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option. If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router: Instead of: match "controller#action" Do: get "controller#action"

Comment: get '/email' => 'profile#email'

returns:
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ProfilesController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: profile

Extracted source (around line #83):
          
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :email, :mobile, :address, :suburb, :postcode, :city, :state, :country)
    end

profiles_controller.rb:83:in `profile_params'
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:45:in `block in update'
app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:44:in `update'

Comment: @sss333 Yes, I think the "email" parameter and "email" method were conflicted. Try to change method name and corresponding route once.

Comment: I did what you said, current situation=

route:
put :email_profile

controller:
def email_profile

view: 
form_tag profile_path(@profile)

I restarted the server and got:
ActionController::ParameterMissing in ProfilesController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: profile
def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :dob, :email, :mobile, :address, :suburb, :postcode, :city, :state, :country)
profiles_controller.rb:83:in `profile_params'
profiles_controller.rb:45:in `block in update'
profiles_controller.rb:44:in `update'

:s so confused!

Comment: @sss333 Again you have written profile_path(@profile) in form_tag, you need to change that to email_profile_path(@profile)

Comment: as before:
email_profile_path(@profile) = NoMethodError in Profiles#show undefined method `email_profile_path'

Comment: @sss333 add route to routes.rb as match '/email_profile' => 'profiles#email_profile'

Comment: added that:
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method. (RuntimeError)
If you want to expose your action to both GET and POST, add `via: [:get, :post]` option.
If you want to expose your action to GET, use `get` in the router:
  Instead of: match "controller#action"
  Do: get "controller#action"

So I tried get '/email_profile' => 'profiles#email_profile'
Routing Error
No route matches [PUT] "/email_profile.1"

Comment: I just saw you edited your answer - the view is not an 'update' view. it's a 'show' view. Does that affect anything?

Comment: Ok, I've been trying a heap of things the past week and I finally have some code that seems to get past this issue. It's not the same as what you've said but used a lot of what you said to get there (:D thanks!) I think the code I  have serves the same purpose as what you've suggested so far. I'm not getting errors anymore but when I send an email as a user it notifies that that the 'email failed.' I've created a new question that starts form where this leaves off as the next part is a slightly different question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560482/why-is-the-email-failing-to-send

Comment: The link starts by showing the final code I ended up with here where: form_tag links to profile path slightly differently, controller includes slightly different @profile = ( I tried yours anusha but it returned an error) and routes worked without the get